# Is it good practice to put if statements in main() or inside functions to respond to user input?

Tags: c++, 2048

I'm writing a 2048 program for the terminal for university.

To play the game my program needs to either shift left, right, up, or down. So I have two options:

1. Write a function that takes the direction as a parameter and then
   acts accordingly through if statements.

   ```
   void move(string direction) {
       if (direction == "up")
           //do stuff
       if (direction == "left")
           //do stuff
       //etc.
   }
   ```
2. Write four functions, one for up, down, left right and put the if statements in `main()`.

   ```
   int main() {
       cin << direction;
       if (direction == up)
           moveup();
       //etc.
   }
   ```

I read google's cpp style guide and it said functions should ideally be kept short. But if I write four functions I will also have a lot of repeated code. As of now I have used option 1 and my `move()` function is 70 lines long.

What is considered better practice?

Comment: googles style guid is very much about the google code base (ie millions of lines of code). Individual items may be applicable to your code or they may not. Iirc each items has pros and cons and a reasoning, so you can decide for your own what style you want to apply.

Comment: what exactly do you mean with repeated code? Can you explain? If your functions have repeated code, then maybe you need more (or less) functions.

Comment: @tobi303 it would be repeated code because as of now, using the direction, I am defining variables at the beginning of my function that indicate how to get to the next tile in my vector. after defining those variables the code is identical for all directions. it just does a different thing because the variables are different.

so if i made four individual functions for the directions i would simply define the variable within each function and then have the same code that does the moving.

Comment: then write a function that contains the identical code and pass the variables that differ between them as parameters. Thats exactly what functions are good for ;)

Answer (score 2):

The second option is generally considered to be the best. I don't see why you would have repeated code, as what move-left (for example) does is likely to be different from what move-up does. And if there *is* repeated code, put that code in yet another function and call it from your move functions. In general, beginner programmers do not write enough functions - it's pretty hard to have too many.

Comment: the only difference between those functions would be in the variables that define where the next tile is with respect to the current tile. the code that does the moving would be identical.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it good practice to put if statements in main() or inside functions to respond to user input?

Both options are fine. The latter option allows re-use of functionality and I recommend it if you have repeating patterns in the main function.

> But if I write four functions I will also have a lot of repeated code.

A solution is to introduce a fifth function, that contains the parts that are common to the other functions. Then call that function from the others. This is what functions are for: partitioning re-usable functionality.